# android build fails - No such file or directory - ./apkbuilder

Tags: android, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm trying to build a package using 
rake run:android 
and I get the error 
No such file or directory - ./apkbuilder

My project setup is given below:

rhodes-3.5.1.12
ndk version: ndk-r8b 32 bit
sdk version: android 4.2.2 API 17

I'd tried with 4.3 API 18 but it's not working.

To reach upto this point I'd copied the file aapt in to platform-tools also created a lib directory in platform-tools and put the dx.lib in it.

I'd tried with different combinations. Rhodes 3.4.2, ndk-r9 64 bit and 32 bit. Only ndk-r8 32 bit is working for me. Could anyone tell me what is the problem here?

Or a working combination of sdk, ndk and rhodes?

I've fixed the issue. Added a new answer below.

Comment: Solved the issue. Find more information in the chat log of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of the missing **apkbuilder.bat** is not coming from the Android NDK but from the Android SDK. Google, in build tools r22 moved some files in different directory, breaking rhodes and a lot of other Android tools.

You've different options:

1. Use RhoMobile Suite v4.0
2. Stick to RhoMobile Suite v.2.2 downloading the latest v3.5 rhodes gem from github (using the 3-5-stable branch).
3. Use Android SDK build tools r21

more information are available on [Launchpad, the RhoMobile community site](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/message/10317#10317) by Motorola Solutions.

Comment: Tried with RhoMobile Suite v4.0 with rhodes-3.5.1.12, ndk-r8b 32 bit, Android 4.0.3 API 15. But the result is same.

Comment: RhoMobile Suite v4.0 includes rhodes-4.0. If you're using rhodes-3.5.1.12 (that is not even the latest v3.5 release) you don't have the fixes to handle the new Android build tools.

Comment: Could you tell me where is rhodes-4.0 located? So that I can configure my build.yml

Comment: If you install RhoMobile Suite v4.0 on windows, you get the rhodes-4.0.0 in the folder: C:\MotorolaRhoMobileSuite4.0.0\ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rhodes-4.0.0  as an alternative you can get the rhodes v4.0 source from github and build the gem from there

Comment: forgot to say that I use mac

Comment: on the mac, using the suggested rvm environment, you are expected to have your ruby gem at ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.x-pxxx/gems/rhodes-x.x.x/lib/framework as indicated in the documentation: http://docs.rhomobile.com/guide/ruby_extensions#adding-libraries-to-rhodes-framework

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39013/discussion-between-coder247-and-pfm)

Comment: 3.Use Android SDK build tools r21 - That did the trick! :D Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it like this in mac os:

Use the latest versions of SDK, NDK and rhodes 4.0.0

Get rhodes like following:

```
git clone git://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes.git
cd rhodes
git checkout 4.0.0 
gem build rhodes.gemspec
sudo gem install rhodes-4.0.0.gem
```

Try to build again. If still not working send me a message, I'll try my best :)

Comment: I was unable to install the gem built using this method. Instead of 'gem build...', just running 'rake gem' worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

### apkbuilder is deprecated.

THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED and may stop working at any time!
current just the batch or bash script be removed

you can just create a new apkbuilder file in android-sdk-linux/tools dir
by:

**window:**

```
  copy android.bat apkbuilder.bat 
  modify apkbuilder.bat: change com.android.sdkmanager.Main to com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain
```

**linux or mac:**

```
  cat android | sed -e 's/com.android.sdkmanager.Main/com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilderMain/g' > apkbuilder
  chmod a+x apkbuilder
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that :

- rhodes 3.5 does not support 64 bits ndk
- some tools are in a different path in ndk9 and rhodes 3.5 can't find them.

So you have to stick with 32 bits and ndk8 with rhodes 3.5.

Rhodes 4 should work with 64 bits and ndk9.